# How to access element like <game:title> with simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse XML feed with SimpleXML, here is a chunk of the XML tree:

```
<item>
<game:name>Tetris</game:name> 
<game:desc>Way Cool Game</game:desc>
<size>5mb</size> 
</item>
```

Well actually, I can succesfully access 'size' with something like that: `$item->size`, but how do I get  value? Of course I can't call like that: `$item->game:name`, and I don't know how what goes after ':' is called. Is it a parameter, attribute or what?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the namespace for game. XML requires all namespaces to be defined. There have been several previous answers about using custom namespaces: 
i.e.

- [How do I parse XML containing custom namespaces using SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133897/how-do-i-parse-xml-containing-custom-namespaces-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [children()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-children.php) function to get the children of the namespace.

```
$useThis = $xmlDoc->children("http://game.namespace/");
```

given that http://game.namespace is the URL to your game namespace in the root node.

Here's an explanation/sample:

- [SimpleXML and namespaces (Oct 2005; by Kevin Yank for Sitepoint)](http://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/)

Answer (score 0):

As for the getting the value of a SimpleXMLElement, you just cast it to a string:

```
$size_value = (string)$item->size;
```