# PHP namespace simplexml problems

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml, xml-namespaces

Evening guys.

Firstly to say, I have read [***How do I parse XML containing custom namespaces using SimpleXML?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133897/how-do-i-parse-xml-containing-custom-namespaces-using-simplexml).

I'm parsing an XML document from a source not mind, and they use a custom namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:moshtix="http://www.moshtix.com.au">
  <channel>
   <item>
    <link>qweqwe</link>
    <moshtix:genre>asdasd</moshtix:genre>
...
```

For example. When I parse using SimpleXML, none of the mostix: namespace elements are on show or accessible. Probably a really simple solution, but any ideas guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, people use [children()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

```
$rss = simplexml_load_string(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:moshtix="http://www.moshtix.com.au">
        <channel>
            <link>qweqwe</link>
            <moshtix:genre>asdasd</moshtix:genre>
        </channel>
    </rss>'
);

foreach ($rss->channel as $channel)
{
    echo 'link: ', $channel->link, "\n";
    echo 'genre: ', $channel->children('moshtix', true)->genre, "\n";
}
```

Comment: While that works for extract each element, which is helpful, quite a lot of the time I need to perform a json_encode and simply bundle up each individual valid item and store them in a database. But when I do this, it doesn't recognise the custom namespace items. Any ideas? The data inside each <item> varies too much to manually put in every one.

Comment: Managed to fix it with a few foreach's scanning through every element ;)

Comment: It always slightly boggles me when people say they're converting XML into JSON without wanting to care about the structure. Why not store it as, well, XML?