# Getting attributes of from xml tag with a namespace

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP namespace simplexml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)

I have a portion of xml as :

```
<item>
    <source url="eurosport.com">Eurosport</source>
    <media:content url="http://media.zenfs.com/en_GB/Sports/Eurosport/900589-15042881-640-360.jpg" type="image/jpeg" width="130" height="86" />
</item>
```

I am using the SimpleXMLElement() to convert the textual xml data into a SimpleXML Element Object. By that I can has access to `item` as `$item`.

I am required to obtain the `url` of `media:content` and am not able to do it. Can anyone help me out?

P.S: Tried this, but it did not help ..

```
foreach ($item->{'media:content'}->attributes() as $key => $val) {
        return (string)$val; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `$item->{'content'}`?  Many simple parsers only require the node name...  You can use the prefix or NS if you like, but it is not often required.

Comment: @jheddings : Just tried that. The loop is not being entered only

Comment: @jheddings is correct, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/J4cn9r

Comment: @Phil : It's not working for me. Tried the following :

return (string) $item->content['url'];

Comment: @jheddings: That only works because the fragmentary XML doesn't include the namespace declaration. If you use `<item xmlns:media="http://example.com">` it will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Use xPath() method of the SimpleXMLElement()

```
var_export($item->xpath('media:content'));
```

Comment: Why does everyone think you need XPath to use namespaces in SimpleXML? You absolutely do not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `->children()` method to select the correct namespace:

```
foreach ($item->children('media', true)->content->attributes() as $key => $val) {
        return (string)$val; 
}
```