# PHP simplexml_load_string cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP namespace simplexml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)

i am fetching an XML String via PHP/cURL and want to use it as a simplexml obejct but it's empty. 
Code:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo 'RESULT VAR:<br>';
echo htmlentities($result).'<br><br>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

echo 'OUTPUT of xml->InsertObservationResponse->AssignedObservationId: <br>';
echo "ID: ".($xml->InsertObservationResponse->AssignedObservationId).'<br>';
```

Produces this output:

```
RESULT VAR:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sos:InsertObservationResponse xmlns:sos="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0"> <sos:AssignedObservationId>o_1626</sos:AssignedObservationId> </sos:InsertObservationResponse>

OUTPUT of xml->InsertObservationResponse->AssignedObservationId:
ID:
```

What I want to output:

```
RESULT VAR:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sos:InsertObservationResponse xmlns:sos="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0"> <sos:AssignedObservationId>o_1626</sos:AssignedObservationId> </sos:InsertObservationResponse>

    OUTPUT of xml->InsertObservationResponse->AssignedObservationId:
    ID: o_1626
```

I also use the simplexml debug lib from https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug 
and

```
simplexml_dump($xml);
```

prints:

```
SimpleXML object (1 item) [ Element { Namespace: 'http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0' Namespace Alias: 'sos' Name: 'InsertObservationResponse' String Content: ' ' Content in Namespace sos Namespace URI: 'http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0' Children: 1 - 1 'AssignedObservationId' Attributes: 0 } ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [children](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) like this:

```
$xml->children('sos', true)->AssignedObservationId;
```