# Php simplexml reading with UBL/different namespaces

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

I have [this kind of xml](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xml/UBL-Order-2.1-Example.xml) document.

My problem is that I cannot read the tags with by simplexml, because the different namespaces. Example `BuyerCustomerParty->Party->Person->FamilyName` tag. `BuyerCustomerParty`, `Party` and `Person` are under `cac`-namespace, but the `FamilyName` is under `cbc`-namespace. Weird is that I can write to the tag and replace the content, but cannot read it before that.

Here some code also:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($value);
$namespaces = $sxe->getDocNamespaces();
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('cbc', $namespaces['cbc']);
$cbc = $sxe->children($namespaces['cbc']); 

//THIS PRINTS THE RIGHT VALUE            
$cbc->IssueDate;

$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('cac', $namespaces['cac']);
$cac = $sxe->children($namespaces['cac']); 

//BUT THIS PRINTS NOTHING
echo $fg = $cac->BuyerCustomerParty->Party->Person->FamilyName;

//BUT IF I CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE TAG... I CAN ACCESS THE TAG
$cac->BuyerCustomerParty->Party->Person->FamilyName = "value";
```

How can I read the tag?

Comment: `xpath` might help. see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788253/simplexml-is-not-parsing-my-epp-xml-messages

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace simplexml problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to include the cbc children down the path.

```
echo $fg = $cac->BuyerCustomerParty->Party->Person->children('cbc',TRUE)->FamilyName;
```