# SimpleXML is not parsing my epp XML messages

Tags: xml, simplexml, epp

I am trying to extract information out of a return xml epp messages from SIDN

But i am not abbel to get some of the variables out of this messages.
I manage to get the result code and messages.

$domaininfo = xml messages that can be seen at : http://pastebin.com/HbXMkdD3

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($domeininfo);
// check result code
    if (isset($xml->response->result))
        { foreach($xml->response->result->attributes() as $name => $value) {
            if ($name === 'code')
            { $code = $value; }
          }
        }

if ($code == '1000')
{
    $domeinnaamuitxml = $xml->response->{'resData'}->{'domain:infData'}->{'domain:name'};
    $techcuitxml = $xml->response->{'resData'}->{'domain:infData'}->{'domain:contact type="tech"'};
    $admincuitxml = $xml->response->{'resData'}->{'domain:infData'}->{'domain:contact type="admin"'};
    echo "Domein naam             :    $domeinnaamuitxml \n";
    echo "Admin C                 :    $admincuitxml \n";
    echo "Tech C                  :    $techcuitxml \n";
}
```

What is it that i am doing wrong

It seam as soon as there is a : - = or " in the tag there is a problem

all help is surely welkom

Comment: SimpleXML does not play nicely with namespaced elements. Use a different XML parser, f.e. DOMDocument.

Comment: @CBroe That statement is just plain wrong. The `->children()` and `->attributes()` methods allow you to use namespaces just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace simplexml problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)

Comment: @IMSoP: Thanks, I should update my knowledge on that part then. The explanation in your user profile is helpful!

Comment: … as are your SimpleXML dump functions on GitHub!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `xpath`to select namespaced elements with `simplexml`:

```
$domeinnaamuitxml = (string)$xml->xpath("//domain:name"}[0];
```

Comment: The above code requires PHP >= 5.4 because of the `[0]` (array dereferencing). In an older version of PHP, do:

```
 $domeinnaamuitxml = $xml->xpath("//domain:name"};
 $domeinnaamuitxml = (string)$domeinnaamuitxml[0];
```

see it working: https://eval.in/101915

Comment: While a useful tool, there is no particular reason to use XPath rather than the main accessors of SimpleXML just because namespaces are involved. The `->children()` and `->attributes()` methods are the simplest way to traverse namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, work great even to get attributes :-D just do ` $admincuitxml = $xml->xpath("//domain:contact[contains(@type, 'admin')]");`

Comment: @IMSoP I find it clumsy to use `children` and then loop through the results to find a specific node, so I prefer `xpath`

Comment: @michi Fair enough, but my point is that's completely orthogonal to the presence of namespaces - it's you can use XPath to search a non-namespaced document, and SimpleXML's traversal methods with a namespaced one.