# Pull XML ID using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I can pull XML data from document not a problem, the problem comes when my client sends over XML documents containing "id". I need to put this XML document (Which is external to my hosting) into a dropdown box so the items can be selected on a form.

Here is the XML in question:

```html
<CAPDataSetResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.capnetwork.co.uk/CAPVehicles/">
<Success>true</Success>
<FailMessage/>
<Returned_DataSet>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="CMan_Code" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="CMan_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<CMan_Code>1</CMan_Code>
<CMan_Name>ALFA ROMEO</CMan_Name>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<CMan_Code>140</CMan_Code>
<CMan_Name>ASTON MARTIN</CMan_Name>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<CMan_Code>164</CMan_Code>
<CMan_Name>AUDI</CMan_Name>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<CMan_Code>836</CMan_Code>
<CMan_Name>BENTLEY</CMan_Name>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
<CMan_Code>869</CMan_Code>
<CMan_Name>BMW</CMan_Name>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</Returned_DataSet>
</CAPDataSetResult>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Will be good if code snippets are reduced to minimum.

Comment: It displays every vehicle manufacturer. I narrowed it down to 5 vehicle makes. So sorry 5 was too much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace simplexml problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems