# Namespaces and XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm exploring XML and PHP, mostly XPath and other parsers.

Here be the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
    <items>
        <item id="7">Pizza</item>
        <item id="8">Cheese</item>
        <item id="9">Cane</item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Here be my path & code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xpath.xml');

$result = $xml -> xpath('/root/actors');

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result,1).'</pre>';
```

Now, said path returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [actor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Christian Bale
                    [1] => Liam Neeson
                    [2] => Michael Caine
                )
        )
)
```

Whereas a seemingly similar line of code, which I would have though would result in the singers, doesnt. Meaning:

```
$result = $xml -> xpath('/root/foo:singers');
```

Results in:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )
```

Now I would've thought the foo: namespace in this case is a non-issue and both paths should result in the same sort of array of singers/actors respectively? How come that is not the case?

Thank-you!

Note: As you can probably gather I'm quite new to xml so please be gentle.

Edit: When I go /root/foo:singers/foo:singer I get results, but not before. Also with just /root I only get actors and items as results, foo:singers are completely omitted.

Comment: Have you seen a few posts [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)? The solution with SimpleXML to get elements outside the default namespace is `children()`, like `var_dump($result[0]->children('foo', true));` passing the namespace prefix as the first arg and `true` as the second to indicate it is a prefix and not a full NS.

Comment: Like @MichaelBerkowski already commented: What you experience is that the element is not within the documents *default namespace*. And `print_r`  is not particularily useful with **SimpleXMLElement** in any case it does show you what's in the default namespace at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML is, for a number of reasons, simply a bad API.

For most purposes I suggest PHP's [DOM extension](http://php.net/dom). (Or for **very** large documents a combination of it along with [XMLReader](http://php.net/xmlreader).)

For using namespaces in xpath you'll want to [register](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php) those you'd like to use, and the prefix you want to use them with, with your [xpath processor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

---

#### Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('xpath.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// The prefix *can* match that used in the document, but it's not necessary.
$xpath->registerNamespace("ns", "http://www.foo.org/");

foreach ($xpath->query("/root/ns:singers") as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
<foo:singers>
    <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
    <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
    <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
</foo:singers>
```

---

[DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) containing matched nodes. You can work with it essentially the same way you would in any other language with a [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) implementation.

Comment: I suggest using `DOMXPath::evaluate()`, not `DOMXPath::query()`. `DOMXPath::query()` doesn't support expressions that return scalar values like `string(/root/ns:singers/ns:singer[@id=5])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `//` expression like:

```
$xml -> xpath( '//foo:singer' );
```

to select all `foo:singer` elements no matter where they are.

**EDIT:**

SimpleXMLElement is selected, you just can't see the child nodes with `print_r()`. Use SimpleXMLElement methods like [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to access them.

```
// example 1
$result = $xml->xpath( '/root/foo:singers' );

foreach( $result as $value ) {
    print_r( $value->children( 'foo', TRUE ) );
}

// example 2
print_r( $result[0]->children( 'foo', TRUE )->singer );
```

Comment: Oh no I understand that, I know how to work around it. I'm just wondering why its happening. Thanks :)