# Traversing XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, traversal

I have the following XML code that I'm trying to parse, but I'm sure of how to traverse some of the data in PHP:

```
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov:8001/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(5360)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2011-06-09T20:15:18Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(5360)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">5360</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2011-06-01T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.04</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.05</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.11</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.18</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.44</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.74</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.6</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.28</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.96</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.83</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">4.15</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">4.15</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
```

I can only get so far as

```
entry->content
```

As the following throws an error for having a colon:

```
entry->content->m:properties
```

How do I access what's inside content such as d:NEW_DATE?

Comment: I am assuming you are using a DOM parser, namespaces (m:) are handled slightly differently.

Comment: Those are namespaced.  You have to do something special to access namespaced notes.  Are you using simplexml?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133897/how-do-i-parse-xml-containing-custom-namespaces-using-simplexml

Comment: Ah I see. I am using SimpleXML. After a quick search and looking at the link Michael provided I guess I'm stuck on how to go two levels (m:properties -> d:NEW_DATE) deep...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SimpleXML you can use the children('prefix', true) and attributes('prefix', true) functions to access namespaced content.

```
entry->content->children('m', true)->properties
```

or to access d:NEW_DATE

```
entry->content->children('m', true)->properties->children('d', true)->NEW_DATE
```

or one step further to access the m:type attribute

```
entry->content->children('m', true)->properties->children('d', true)->NEW_DATE->attributes('m', true)->type
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do it by including the uri of the schema in children(), but was also trying to figure out how to do it without having to include the uri!  Do you know if there is a difference in speed the two methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleXml's functions
[SimpleXML](http://php.net/book.simplexml)

But my fav class is [DOMDocument](http://php.net/class.domdocument)