# How to traverse xml in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am using the following function

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
$myTestingUrl = file_get_contents_curl("myUrl");
```

After I run that function I have

```
$myTestingUrl =
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
    <entry key="keyName">
        <entry key="ActionUrl">http://www.my_actionUrl.com/</entry>
    </entry>
</map>
```

Can you please tell me how can I traverse $myTestingUrl to get the content of entry key "ActionUrl" (http://www.my_actionUrl.com/) in a variable in php?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traversing XML in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301084/traversing-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myTestingUrl );
$items = $xml->xpath('/map/entry/entry[@key="ActionUrl"]/text()');
echo $items[0];
```

Comment: Good one! Here is more info on [simpleXML](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp)

Comment: On the last line i receive the following error: Notice: Undefined index: 0

Comment: Copy the code from http://eval.in/2767 and try if it is working. If it is working, then `echo` your xml and check it for any difference.

Comment: Seems like my server was having simpleXml disabled. Both of the solutions are working! Thanks a lot! :)

Ps. On my server just echo $xml->entry->entry.PHP_EOL; is display the right value.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer @air4x's XPath method but here it is without XPath - for the purpose of showing element and attribute access in [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/Xx31t4bM)

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($myTestingUrl);

foreach($obj->entry as $entry)
{
    if(isset($entry->entry))
    {
        foreach($entry->entry->attributes() as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key == 'key' && $value == 'ActionUrl')
            {
                echo 'ActionUrl is: ' . (string)$entry->entry;
                break 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a blank page and no answer for this one.
I've made the following steps:

`echo $myTestingUrl; (prints out <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map><entry key="keyName"><entry key="ActionUrl">http://urlllll/library.xml</entry></entry></map>)

$obj = simplexml_load_string($myTestingUrl);
foreach($obj->entry as $entry){
  if(isset($entry->entry)){
    foreach($entry->entry->attributes() as $key => $value){
      if($key == 'key' && $value == 'ActionUrl'){
   echo 'ActionUrl is: ' . (string)$entry->entry;
   break 1;
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @CSSensei you must have an error in some other code, this code works (as seen on the codepad demo). Have a look in your error log.

Comment: I have no other code on my page just this for testing it.
On codepad there's that trim function. Is that mandatory for the extraction to work?

Comment: Try adding the trim like `simplexml_load_string(trim($myTestingUrl))`, I used it in the demo because I added a newline before the opening xml tag, just for readability.

Comment: Seems like my server was having simpleXml disabled. Both of the solutions are working! Thanks a lot!