# How do I parse an XML response with PHP that has namespaces?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file that has namespaces in it using simplexml_load_string in PHP.  A sample of the xml response is here: http://pastie.org/4404714

Usually I would parse this using the simplexml_load_string command and then dump the results out to get a nice easy to read tree so that I can access the objects.  However, all of the data does not even show up when I do this in this case.  The segments below the AttributeSets don't show up at all.  I have to output the raw xml to even see them.

I read in other similar stackoverflow answers that I could just ignore the namespace portion in the tags, but I can't get that to work either.  Could someone please help.  For example, how would I print out Author, Height, or Edition from this response.  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML containing custom namespaces using SimpleXML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133897/how-do-i-parse-xml-containing-custom-namespaces-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found two ways to solve. One is the correct way, and other is quick and dirty.  [This is the site](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302) which explains how to do it the right way.  I was able to parse the string using `simple_xml_load_string` in PHP, then get the children of the object that contained the different namespace just like in the example on that page.  That was a pain but doable.

Finally, since I just needed a simple, quick solution, I took the raw XML data and did a `str_replace('ns2:','',$rawxml)`, then parsed it with `simple_xml_load_string` and it works like a charm.  I just `$call->it->like->this`.

Some people will not like this solution, but namespaces are used to avoid duplicate fields, and because of the nature of the way I am parsing and using the data, this will not be an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml) will help you.

Basically what the answer suggests is that you have to register the namespace for each simpleXMLElement object you use.

example from the linked question:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($r);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('e', 'http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event');

foreach($xml->xpath('//e:event') as $event) {
    $event->registerXPathNamespace('e', 'http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/event');
    var_export($event->xpath('//e:sessionKey'));
}
```

Or as another solution explains: it does work without registerXPathNamespace and the full namespace prefix in the xpath queries:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($r);

foreach($xml->xpath('//event:event') as $event) {
    var_export($event->xpath('event:sessionKey'));
}
```

Comment: I read that question and attempted the answer, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my situation.  The layout of the XML in that example is different than mine in the sample I posted.  Does anyone have any idea how to write that so that it will work with my sample xml?