# PHP : Get XML Value with colon and attributes

Tags: php, xml

Below is the Xml file,, I need to retreive value between `<im:name> and </im:name>` , i.e **Dental Surgery** .and also value between  `<im:image height="75"> and  </im:image>` , i.e  `http://a478.phobos.apple.com/.75x75-65.png`

```
<entry>
   <im:name>Dental Surgery</im:name>  
    <im:image height="53">
    http://a1962.phobos.apple.com/53x53-50.png
    </im:image>
    <im:image height="75">
    http://a478.phobos.apple.com/.75x75-65.png
    </im:image>
    <im:image height="100">
    http://a683.phobos.apple.com/100x100-75.png
    </im:image>
</entry>
```

I tried below code but dont work

```
  $entry->im->name;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133897/how-do-i-parse-xml-containing-custom-namespaces-using-simplexml ?

Comment: It does not work for me.